# Send push notification via PHP

Tags: php, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I know this is an already exploited topic on SO but I'm struggling with a particular configuration.

I'm using a dedicated server to send push notification to ios devices. From this server I can successfully connect via telnet to the APNS gateway:

```
[root@..... luca]# telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.110.227.35...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I've correctly generated the CA certificate and the combined cert and key from apple and I can test an OpenSSL connection using them correctly:

```
[root@... luca]#  openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -key server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -CApath entrust_2048_ca.cer 

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.... hidden cert here ....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Root CA
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Application Integration Certification Authority
---
SSL handshake has read 3160 bytes and written 2158 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: .... master key here ....
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1437564170
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I can also use Mac Os X [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) to succesfully send push notifications using that certificates from my development box.

I tried to use ApnsPHP using a modified version of their sample code:

```
<?php
// Adjust to your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
// Using Autoload all classes are loaded on-demand
require_once 'ApnsPHP/ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';
// Instantiate a new ApnsPHP_Push object
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
        ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
        /*'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'*/
        'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'
);
// Set the Provider Certificate passphrase
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_2048_ca.cer');
// Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->connect();
// Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient
$message = new ApnsPHP_Message('5ad1fafb8efdec85fc3e51ea0075d342d18bad9e56cf3e014b56ea9fc4f184bd');
// Set a custom identifier. To get back this identifier use the getCustomIdentifier() method
// over a ApnsPHP_Message object retrieved with the getErrors() message.
$message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");
// Set badge icon to "3"
$message->setBadge(3);
// Set a simple welcome text
$message->setText('Hello APNs-enabled device!');
// Play the default sound
$message->setSound();
// Set a custom property
$message->setCustomProperty('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));
// Set another custom property
$message->setCustomProperty('acme3', array('bing', 'bong'));
// Set the expiry value to 30 seconds
$message->setExpiry(30);
// Add the message to the message queue
$push->add($message);
// Send all messages in the message queue
$push->send();
// Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->disconnect();
// Examine the error message container
$aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
        var_dump($aErrorQueue);
}
?>
```

This results in an error when invoked from console:

```
[root@..... luca]# php index.php 
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:47 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Trying tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:47 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:47 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Retry to connect (1/3)...
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:48 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Trying tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...    
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:49 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:49 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Retry to connect (2/3)...
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:50 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Trying tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...    
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:50 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:50 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Retry to connect (3/3)...
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: INFO: Trying tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...   
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:30:52 +0200 ApnsPHP[19972]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
```

This is quite weird, I've tried several minor fix including commeting out the verify_peer section in Abstract.php but none worked. I am missing something here, have any of you any idea on how to fix this?

I've been sending push notification from Java and Python for a while so I'm quite confident about the whole process. It's my first time with PHP anyway.

Comment: Does your PHP have SSL and TLS support?

Comment: http://elbuild.com/luca/info.php i believe it has. AM i correct?

Comment: Yes, it has TLS and SSL support.

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the ports?

Comment: According to the fact i can Connect via telnet i would say no. Have you seen the top part of my post?

Comment: Yeah, but firewalls can be application specific. It's pretty hard to say, since your error messages are just default non-specific error messages.

Comment: It's my own server I'm pretty sure  there's no firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but still I am contributing my comments to send push notification for iOS/iPhone as I have gone through the same issue once:

I was able to connect through telnet over apple sandbox server but not with PHP socket script as it was giving gateway connection error. Please follow below steps:

1. Check PHP configuration ( ini ) so as to confirm SSL and socket
   enabled.
2. No firewall related restriction.
3. Try some core PHP test notification separately. You may find one [here](http://prashantpandeytech.blogspot.in/2015/09/iphone-ios-and-android-push.html)
4. Now openssl should verify your pem and passphrase should be confirmed.

Note: if you have generated IPA for your APP then try with your production pem rather than development pem.